# file was built for unsupported file format?

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors

I'm on OS X and I get a compilation error when I try to execute this command in terminal

> g++ -Wall -o test_E test_E.cpp dynamic_array.cpp oracle.o

My other c++ files such as `test_A.cpp` and `test_B.cpp` run fine on the same command but without the last part, e.g.

> g++ -Wall -o test_A test_A.cpp dynamic_array.cpp

I also tried running the command without `oracle.o` and it gives the same error, but without the unsupported file format

How could I fix this?

```
ld: warning: ignoring file oracle.o, file was built for unsupported file 
format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): oracle.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"oracle::insert(int, int)", referenced from:
  generate_oracle(oracle&, int, int, int) in test_E-2b7bb8.o
  run_tests(dynamic_array&, oracle&) in test_E-2b7bb8.o
 "oracle::operator[](unsigned int)", referenced from:
  print_state(dynamic_array&, oracle&) in test_E-2b7bb8.o
  compare_content(dynamic_array&, oracle&) in test_E-2b7bb8.o
"oracle::get_allocated_size() const", referenced from:
  print_state(dynamic_array&, oracle&) in test_E-2b7bb8.o
  compare_content(dynamic_array&, oracle&) in test_E-2b7bb8.o
 "oracle::get_size() const", referenced from:
  print_state(dynamic_array&, oracle&) in test_E-2b7bb8.o
  compare_exceptions(dynamic_array&, oracle&) in test_E-2b7bb8.o
  compare_content(dynamic_array&, oracle&) in test_E-2b7bb8.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is test_E.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>

 #include "dynamic_array.h"
 #include "oracle.h"

 using namespace std;

void generate_cut(dynamic_array &cut, int start, int delta, int count) {
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    cut.insert(start, i);
    start += delta;
   }
}

void generate_oracle(oracle &orc, int start, int delta, int count) {
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    orc.insert(start, i);
    start += delta;
     }
  }

void print_state(dynamic_array &cut, oracle &orc) {
 cout << "***** cut" << endl;
 cout << "size: " << cut.get_size() << endl;
 cout << "allocated size: " << cut.get_allocated_size() << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < cut.get_size(); i++) {
    cout << cut[i] << " ";
    if (i > 50) { // avoid lengthy output
        cout << " ...";
        break;
    }
  }
 cout << endl;

 cout << "***** oracle" << endl;
 cout << "size: " << orc.get_size() << endl;
 cout << "allocated size: " << orc.get_allocated_size() << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < orc.get_size(); i++) {
    cout << orc[i] << " ";
    if (i > 50) { // avoid lengthy output
        cout << " ...";
        break;
    }
 }
 cout << endl;
 }

int const_f(const dynamic_array &cut, int i) {
  return cut[i];
 }

int compare_exceptions(dynamic_array &cut, oracle &orc) {
{
// ********** operator[]
int indexes[] = {orc.get_size(), orc.get_size()+1000};
int N = sizeof(indexes)/sizeof(int);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int caught = 0;
    try {
        cut[indexes[i]];
    } catch (dynamic_array::exception) {
        caught = 1;
    }
    if (!caught) {
        cout << "operator[]: uncaught index range exception at: ";
        cout << indexes[i] << endl;
        return 0;
    }
   }
  }

  {
   // ********** operator[] const
  int indexes[] = {orc.get_size(), orc.get_size()+1000};
  int N = sizeof(indexes)/sizeof(int);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int caught = 0;
    try {
        cut[indexes[i]];
    } catch (dynamic_array::exception) {
        caught = 1;
    }
    if (!caught) {
        cout << "operator[] const: uncaught index range exception at: ";
        cout << indexes[i] << endl;
        return 0;
    }
   }
  }

 {
  // ********** insert(int,int)
 int indexes[] = {-1000, -1, orc.get_size()+1, orc.get_size()+1000};
 int N = sizeof(indexes)/sizeof(int);
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int caught = 0;
    try {
        cut.insert(0, indexes[i]);
    } catch (dynamic_array::exception) {
        caught = 1;
    }
    if (!caught) {
        cout << "insert(int,int): uncaught index range exception at: ";
        cout << indexes[i] << endl;
        return 0;
    }
   }
  }

 {
  // ********** insert(dynamic_array&,int)
  int indexes[] = {-1000, -1, orc.get_size()+1, orc.get_size()+1000};
  int N = sizeof(indexes)/sizeof(int);
  dynamic_array a;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int caught = 0;
    try {
        cut.insert(a, indexes[i]);
    } catch (dynamic_array::exception) {
        caught = 1;
    }
    if (!caught) {
        cout << "insert(dynamic_array&,int): uncaught index range exception  at: ";
        cout << indexes[i] << endl;
        return 0;
    }
   }
  }

 {
  // ********** remove(int)
  int indexes[] = {-1000, -1, orc.get_size(), orc.get_size()+1000};
  int N = sizeof(indexes)/sizeof(int);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int caught = 0;
    try {
        cut.remove(indexes[i]);
    } catch (dynamic_array::exception) {
        caught = 1;
    }
    if (!caught) {
        cout << "remove(int): uncaught index range exception at: ";
        cout << indexes[i] << endl;
        return 0;
    }
   }
  }

 {
  // ********** remove(int,int)
  // start out of range
  int start_indexes[] = {-1000, -1, orc.get_size()+1, orc.get_size()+1000};
  int N = sizeof(start_indexes)/sizeof(int);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int caught = 0;
    try {
        cut.remove(start_indexes[i], orc.get_size());
    } catch (dynamic_array::exception) {
        caught = 1;
    }
    if (!caught) {
        cout << "remove(int,int): uncaught index range exception at: ";
        cout << start_indexes[i] << "," << orc.get_size() << endl;
        return 0;
    }
   }

   // end out of range
   int end_indexes[] = {orc.get_size()+1, orc.get_size()+1000};
   N = sizeof(end_indexes)/sizeof(int);
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int caught = 0;
    try {
        cut.remove(0, end_indexes[i]);
    } catch (dynamic_array::exception) {
        caught = 1;
    }
    if (!caught) {
        cout << "remove(int,int): uncaught index range exception at: ";
        cout << end_indexes[i] << "," << orc.get_size() << endl;
        return 0;
    }
   }

   // special case: 0 <= end < start < size
   int caught = 0;
   try {
    cut.remove(1, 0);
   } catch (dynamic_array::exception) {
    caught = 1;
   }
   if (!caught) {
    cout << "remove(int,int): uncaught index range exception at: 1,0" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  }

  return 1; // no failures detected
  }

   int compare_content(dynamic_array &cut, oracle &orc) {
  // check size
  if (cut.get_size() != orc.get_size()) {
    cout << "ERROR. ";
    cout << "size. cut: " << cut.get_size();
    cout << " orc:" << orc.get_size() << endl;

    print_state(cut, orc);
    return 0;
   }

   // check get_allocated_size
   if (cut.get_allocated_size() != orc.get_allocated_size()) {
    cout << "ERROR. ";
    cout << "allocated_size. cut:" << cut.get_allocated_size();
    cout << " orc:" << orc.get_allocated_size() << endl;

    print_state(cut, orc);
    return 0;
   }

  // check operator[] and operator[] const
  for (int i = 0; i < orc.get_size(); i++) {
    if (cut[i] != orc[i]) {
        cout << "ERROR. ";
        cout << "cut[" << i << "]:" << cut[i];
        cout << " orc[" << i << "]:" << orc[i] << endl;

        print_state(cut, orc);
        return 0;
    }

    int x = const_f(cut, i);
    if (x != orc[i]) {
        cout << "ERROR. ";
        cout << "cut[" << i << "]:" << cut[i];
        cout << " orc[" << i << "]:" << x << endl;

        print_state(cut, orc);
        return 0;
    }
   }

  return 1;
   }

void run_tests(dynamic_array &cut, oracle &orc) {
compare_content(cut, orc);
compare_exceptions(cut, orc);

cut.insert(1, 0);
orc.insert(1, 0);

compare_content(cut, orc);
compare_exceptions(cut, orc);

 }

int main() {
 dynamic_array cut;
 generate_cut(cut, 0, 2, 5);

 oracle orc;
 generate_oracle(orc, 0, 2, 5);

 run_tests(cut, orc);
 }
```

Comment: `45 4C 46` = `ELF`. Your oracle.o file is a Linux ELF binary, not an OS X Mach-O.

Comment: so what do u think i can do?

Comment: The file oracle.o was given to us by my teacher..

Comment: Does your teacher expect you to be able to compile this on OS X? Unless you have the source code for oracle.o to compile it for other platforms, or the time to work though disassembling, convert, and reassembling, you will need to use the same platform the object file was compiled for.

Comment: He didn't specify.. but i'm now switching to ubuntu and I'll try if it works

Comment: You're the best :) it worked... thank you so much .. why not answer question so i vote you up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This this case, your problem is you are trying to link a Linux ELF binary, as evidenced by the hex dump of the header it output (`0x45 0x4C 0x46` = `ELF`).

Possible solutions based on the resources you have available:

1. Use the same platform as the object file was compiled for (your solution in this case).
2. Obtain an object file for your platform (for OS X, you would need a Mach-O matching your architecture, in your case x86_64).
3. Obtain the source code for the object file, and compile it for your platform.
4. Disassemble, convert assembly as necessary, and assemble a new binary (probably in-feasible unless it's very small and the implementation is unknown).