# Troubles linking an object file to a C file in a Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I've been given an object file `set.o*` as well as the header file `set.h`. I need to run tests on the functions in the file I've created, `main.c`. I've written the following `Makefile`

```
all: main

main: main.c set.h set.o
    clang -Wall -g main.c set.o -o main

clean:
    rm main
```

This `Makefile` keeps giving me the error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file set.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 )
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_validateMemUse", referenced from:
      _main in main-f6a155.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

If anyone knows where I went wrong, a reply would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If not suppressed with `@` or `.SILENT`, `make` will normally print all commands, and I would expect more error messages. Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the complete output. If the `clang` command line does not show more output, try running it with option `-v` as suggested.

Comment: My apologies, the post has been updated with the full output

Comment: Ummm the first line of all the error messages seems pretty self explanatory…

Comment: @KyJames With your simple `Makefile`, we can guess that the executed command is exactly as written there: `clang -Wall -g main.c set.o -o main`. With variables it might get more difficult. You should always copy&paste both the command and the error message. From where did you get the file `set.o`?

Comment: I guess after he read the error message he figured it out and ghosted us. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The error is quite clear, here cut down to the important statement with emphasis by me:

> ld: warning: **ignoring file set.o**, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for **unknown-unsupported** file format

Apparently the file "set.o" was compiled for another target system, or is not an object file. In any case, the linker cannot recognize it and therefore is not able to link your "main.c" to it.

Get back to the person who gave you this file and ask for an object file for your Mac, or even better the source.

---

*Note: Your Makefile is OK.*

Comment: Based on the file header, it appears to be a Linux ELF file, as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518941/file-was-built-for-unsupported-file-format